# Convert single row tsv file into multiple row tsv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a tsv file which is single row.

e.g.:

```
onset   duration    stimulus    16.100000   3.000000    tasteless   26.700000   3.000000.1  control 31.700000   ... 150.6   729.900000  3.000000.60 rinse.26    745.600000  3.000000.61 112.5cal.6  751.600000  3.000000.62 rinse.27

0 rows × 192 columns
```

What I intend to do is, afte every third element, add a new line character i.e to next row so the above dataframe should look as follows:

```
onset   duration    stimulus
16.100000   3.000000    tasteless
26.700000   3.000000    control
31.700000   3.000000    rinse
48.400000   3.000000    tasteless
60.000000   3.000000    tasteless
76.600000   3.000000    tasteless
91.300000   3.000000    tasteless
103.900000  3.000000    0cal
111.900000  3.000000    rinse
127.600000  3.000000    0cal
131.600000  3.000000    rinse
150.2000
```

I tried

```
"\n".join(["\t".join(df[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,len(df),3)])
```

But of no help. Also tried converting the dtaframe into text and replacing every 3rd `\t` with `\n`.

Can we rather do it using pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read in the tsv, reshape the values, then create a new dataframe.

```
In [428]: df = pd.read_csv('test.tsv', header=None, delim_whitespace=True); df.values
Out[428]: 
array([['onset', 'duration', 'stimulus', 16.1, 3.0, 'tasteless', 26.7,
        '3.000000.1', 'control', 31.7, '...', 150.6, 729.9, '3.000000.60',
        'rinse.26', 745.6, '3.000000.61', '112.5cal.6', 751.6,
        '3.000000.62', 'rinse.27']], dtype=object)

In [434]: cols = df.values.reshape(-1, 3)

In [435]: df = pd.DataFrame(cols[1:], columns=cols[0]); df
Out[435]: 
   onset     duration    stimulus
0   16.1            3   tasteless
1   26.7   3.000000.1     control
2   31.7          ...       150.6
3  729.9  3.000000.60    rinse.26
4  745.6  3.000000.61  112.5cal.6
5  751.6  3.000000.62    rinse.27
```

After this, writing back to a tsv is simple:

```
In [440]: df.to_csv('out.tsv', sep='\t')
```